# Fullcalendar Now() Indicator positioned wrongly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In Fullcalendar, when setting the parameters

> mintime

and

> maxtime

the Now() indicators is not positioned properly.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eufnL925/2/) to show the issue.
In this Fiddle I would expect the indicator at the current date and time, however it is positioned at the top of the column of "yesterday"

Below is the code used in the fiddle

**HTML**

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    height: 600,
    nowIndicator: 'true',
    minTime: "20:00:00", // this makes the calendar start at 8PM
    maxTime: "44:00:00", // this makes the calender end 24 hours later at 8PM ( (8PM => 20) + 24 = 44)
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'
})
```

Removing the

> minTime

and

> maxTime

parameters, makes the Now indicator position properly, as shown here
https://jsfiddle.net/8jndrp7m/2/

How can I position the Now indicator properly when using minTime and maxTime?
Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem look like that you are set maxTime for next day which why it not working

If you like specify date to set max use validRange to set min & max date

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek', //agendaWeek
        validRange: {
          start: '2017-05-01',
          end: '2017-06-01'
        },
        locale: 'nl',
        timezone: 'local',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
        height: 600,
        slotDuration: '00:10:00',
        nowIndicator: 'true',
       minTime: "17:00:00", // this makes the calendar start at 8PM
       maxTime: "20:00:00", // this makes the calender end 24 hours later at 8PM ( (8PM => 20) + 24 = 44) 
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        editable: true, // enable draggable events
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    })
```

Comment: Although it did not solve my issue, @dwarka-tiwari explained WHY it works as it does

Answer (score 1):

i see multiple problems:

1. the now indicator doesn't need quotes, change `'true'` to `true`,
2. If you want to extend the maxtime past midnight you can just put a `1.` in front of the time, to set times the next day.So 8 in the morning on next day would be `maxTime: '1.08:00:00'`
3. If you start the calendar at 8 in the evening and its not 8pm yet (at least in my timezone) the now indicator will not show properly

Comment: Ok ,thanks for the tips (1 and 2).
Apparently this is an issue with Fullcalendar, that it does not know how to show the Now() indicator, when the starttime of today has not yet been reached.

Comment: @JoostvanderDrift what do you mean exactly? What do you expect to happen with the now indicator in that case? It can't indicate what time it is now if that time is not on the calendar

Comment: my view runs from 8PM yesterday to 8PM today. Today at 9AM the now indicator is shown at the top of the view (so at 8PM yesterday) while 9AM IS in the view.